How to extract only visible text from pdf page?
I am trying to extract the text from pdf, but the problem it is also reading the hidden text as well.
How I could solve this?
I tried below code
    public static void iTextExample() {
    String pdfFilePath = "path_to_pdf_file.pdf";
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
                    int pageNo = 10;
        String pageContent = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,pageNo);
        System.out.println("Page Content: \n" + pageContent);
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

but the code also reading the hidden text.
example:
Visible text on page
Contents at a Glance
Introduction xxiii
Chapter 1 Introduction  1
Chapter 2 Mechanisms 17
Chapter 3 Technologies 39
...
Index
Text after extraction from iText
Stuttard   f? rs.indd   V4 - 08/17/2011 Page viii
Contents at a Glance
Introduction xxiii
Chapter 1 Introduction  1
Chapter 2 Mechanisms 17
Chapter 3 Technologies 39
...
Index 853
viii
ffirs.inddffirs.indd   viiiviii 8/19/20118/19/2011   12:22:38 PM12:22:38 PM

Content after reading it
Stuttard   ffi rs.indd   V4 - 08/17/2011 Page viii
viii
Contents at a Glance
Introduction xxiii
Chapter 1 Web Application (In)security 1
Chapter 2 Core Defense Mechanisms 17
Chapter 3 Web Application Technologies 39
Chapter 4 Mapping the Application 73
Chapter 5 Bypassing Client-Side Controls 117
Chapter 6 Attacking Authentication 159
Chapter 7 Attacking Session Management 205
Chapter 8 Attacking Access Controls 257
Chapter 9 Attacking Data Stores 287
Chapter 10 Attacking Back-End Components 357
Chapter 11 Attacking Application Logic 405
Chapter 12 Attacking Users: Cross-Site Scripting 431
Chapter 13 Attacking Users: Other Techniques 501
Chapter 14 Automating Customized Attacks 571
Chapter 15 Exploiting Information Disclosure 615
Chapter 16 Attacking Native Compiled Applications 633
Chapter 17 Attacking Application Architecture 647
Chapter 18 Attacking the Application Server 669
Chapter 19 Finding Vulnerabilities in Source Code 701
Chapter 20 A Web Application Hacker�s Toolkit 747
Chapter 21 A Web Application Hacker�s Methodology 791
Index 853
ffirs.indd viii   8/19/2011 12:22:38 PM

There are really many ways to make text invisible, and there have been multiple q&a on that topic here on stack overflow. Habe you checked whether the answers and solutions to them help you? Your code seems to indicate you didn't.

I am trying to find out those solution, posting a question for the same is also a indication that I have not found any solution yet. If you know any reference then posting that reference would be helpful. Thanks.

@Aakash "posting a question for the same is also a indication that I have not found any solution yet. If you know any reference then posting that reference would be helpful." - Of course, have you e.g. tried the PDFVisibleTextStripper from this answer? (Beware, at the time of its writing PDFBox 2 was current, so some changes may be necessary to work with PDFBox 3.) If it does not work for you, we'd need representative example PDFs for analysis; as mentioned above, there are many ways written text may be invisible in a PDF...

@Aakash Is KJ right in assuming your "hidden text" only is text outside the crop box, not  text made invisible by other mechanisms?

@mkl Actually this is not about only one book there can be other books, and my concern was just extracting the visible text. For this particular book "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook" may be @K J is right.

@K J I tried the solution provided by Bruno Lowagie ( iText Devoloper) the solution is not good approach in my case. Because There can be different PDFs and this is not guaranteed the invisible text is always in Header or Footer it can be anywhere in the entire PDF page.

This is a common problem. That text extraction will try to find all text within the "Page" definition.
If lucky you may see white text on a transparent background. Or if using OCR see invisible text as readable thus extractable.
There is a fairly similar PDFBox question, however NOT duplicate question, as that has a similar marginal issue, YET different reason. Where text is inside the viewers page.

You could try that complex solution and see if it works in your case too.
Also it mentions other attempts Why are there invisible characters in my PDF and how do I filter them out with PDFBox?
In this case it is simpler than that, as the text like any other, is black text on a transparent background. However since the text is only intended for job control (not human consumption), it has been placed outside the crop marks.
         Stuttard      fﬁrs.indd      V4 - 08/17/2011 Page viii




  Contents        at       a      Glance


  Introduction xxiii
  Chapter 1           Web Application (In)security          1
  Chapter 2           Core Defense Mechanisms              17


Most PDFtoTEXT extractors have a means to confine a "range of interest" to just the core page data, thus ignoring the marginal headers footers or aside comments like watermarks, footnotes etc.
The best way to avoid problems is ask the author for the latest body text.

Thanks for this useful information, Is there any way to overcome this issue? or what approach should I follow to solve this problem?. I am trying to build my own PDFReader Class to read pdf raw data and parse it in human readable form because I thought this could be one possible solution but it is very complex task.

You can subclass LocationTextExtractionStrategy, override the eventOccured method and apply a filter based on the location with renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint() and renderInfo.getBaseline().getEndPoint().
When the location is on the page's visible part, you can call the parent eventOccured method.

Yes, as long it is indeed merely a question of filtering off-page material, that would be the way to go. But in a comment to the question the op said it is not guaranteed the invisible text is always in Header or Footer it can be anywhere in the entire PDF page. Thus, for their general task other methods are necessary.

@mkl You are absolutely right.
